# Force HTTPS via URL rewrite in web.config

Tags: iis, azure, url-rewriting, web-config

I'm trying to force HTTPS via a web.config URL rewrite rule for a URL which includes a path.

eg http://my.domain.com/folder must be forced to use https://my.domain.com/folder

I'd also like to force HTTPS for all pages on their relative paths

eg http:// my.domain.com/folder/page.aspx forced to https:// my.domain.com/folder/page.aspx

This is what I have:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Redirect to https">
        <match url="(.*)"/>
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="Off"/>
          <add input=”{REQUEST_METHOD}” pattern=”^get$|^head$” />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"/>
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this URL rewrite rule:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="HTTP/S to HTTPS Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
          <add input="{SERVER_PORT_SECURE}" pattern="^0$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your casing and the type of quotes you are using.  Also, the 2nd input method is invalid - the pattern isn't valid a regex.  This rule works for what you want:

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks! I had tried something similar, but the experience is that it redirects to https ://my.domain.com without the trailing path